# Add data-tooltip to simple form syntax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, simple-form

this is one of the things I normally spend many hours trying many combinations, but today did not work.

I want to add Foundations data tooltip to a simple_form input, and I can't match the correct syntax.

Without simpleform:

```
data-tooltip class="has-tip" title="Borrar este spot definitivamente"
```

With simpleform:

```
:html => {:"data-tooltip" => 'class="has-tip"' 'title="Borrar este spot definitivamente"'}
```

Thanks

Comment: Try: `:data => { :tooltip => true} `? Never used simple_form though, but creating 'data' attributes for HTML in rails works the way I mentioned.

Comment: @Surya And how about the message in the tooltip? also, I think Foundation needs the 'has-tip' class in order to apply it's tooltip effect!

Comment: Try the answer I've posted. I think that should work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this

```
<%= f.input :field_name, input_html: { "data-tooltip" => true, :class => "has-tip", :title => "Bla bla bla" } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
:html => {:data => { :tooltip => true }, :class=> "has-tip", :title => "Borrar este spot definitivamente"}
```

Comment: Ahh what's the HTML being generated? Can you please post the form code?

Comment: I can't see the tooltip in the HTML:<input class="string required" id="contact_name" name="contact[name]" type="text">